# Date conversion with Delphi 5 not working on 64 bit ma

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi 5 program that I wrote and compiled on a Windows 8.1 32 bit machine.   It reads a date from a text file and converts with strtodate().   This works on the 32 bit pc but i have copied the .exe to my 64 bit laptop (Windows 7)and I get the error '24/4/2015' is not a valid date.   The Region, language, date settings are the same on both machines and the only difference I can think of is that the laptop is 64 bit.   Would this affect the date conversion?

Comment: It won't be anything to do with 64 bit. Your regional settings will differ. Inspect them from delphi code. Also, are you sure you want the locale settings to be an input to your program? Do you really want your program to work correctly in certain locations only?

Comment: So look at the value of ShortDateFormat and DateSeparator. You could have worked this out by reading the documentation. It describes how StrToDate works. If StrToDate behaves differently then it must be receiving different input. If you pass the same string, then the difference must be in the other input, the format settings.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps I was wrong about 64 bit. @ain has found a bug report that points the finger at it being a Windows bug. But a Win 7 bug. Anyway, my diagnostics advice is sound. As is my suggestion that relying on the locale for conversions might be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I have written the program purely for my own use so  did not consider distribution needs.   I am in what will probably be the last decade of my life and dug out my old copy of Delphi 5 to enjoy the stimulation that programming brings!   I tried tha change to SysUtils suggested elsewhere but that did not work, however setting the

Comment: region to Germany and then back to English(UK) on the laptop did work.

Comment: I think if you'd done the debugging that I suggested you would have found the discrepancy. It's important to understand how DateToStr works

Answer (score 0):

This might be the "[ShortDateFormat in Win7 64-bit always returning default](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80189)" bug. Solution seems to be to add somewhere in the program init code following snippet:

```
SetThreadLocale(GetUserDefaultLCID);
GetFormatSettings;
```

Comment: The defect appears to be in Windows, hence cannot fix resolution